# Does PlayStation 2 wireless controllers really works well?

Tags: controllers, ps2

Last days I was mentioning about the glory of PS2 times and it would be nice to pull out this old console from the basement and have some fun with it one more time.

The problem is that PS2 controllers are wired, so I will be forced to sit very close to the TV and watch out about the cable connecting console and controller. I saw in some market portals some 3rd party wireless controllers matching to PS2 controllers sockets.

Did anybody here have the pleasure of using this type of gear? Does it works fine and allows you to enjoy the playing on PS2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to use [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0001VNNE8) controllers back in the day. Each controller came with a dongle that fit the PS2 controller port. Similar to how wireless controllers are paired these days on some newer consoles, you would press a button to activate the controller's "seeking" mode, and then press a button on the dongle to pair it. A simple pair of AA batteries will keep them topped up.

In fact, when my parents <strike>forced me</strike> suggested that I sell my PS2, I gave two of those Logitech controllers to my friend. We still use them to this day, some 12 years later, for nights of nostalgic 007: Nightfire. They've last this long, which is a testament to their quality and usability.

Comment: Sounds like a very comfortable solution for me. I think about locating my PS2 in the bedroom, so it may help me with comfortable playing and lying on the bed without having to lean forward because of the cable